# Django edit profile not saving

Tags: django, django-users

I have pre-filled forms for my user (the django user + my profile one with more informations) that just doesn't want to be saved. No error message, no redirection, I press the button "edit", and then... same page, with the modifications already written. But the database isn't changed.

So, here is the code :

forms.py :

```
class UpdateUser(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Cette adresse email est déjà utilisée, veuillez en indiquer une autre')
        return email


class UpdateProfil(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profil
        fields = ("society", "thingA", "thingB", "thingC", "thingD", "thingE")
```

views.py :

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
    profile = Profil.objects.get(user = user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UpdateUser(request.POST, instance=user)
        form2 = UpdateProfil(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Register/view_profile.html')
    else:
        form1 = UpdateUser(initial={"email": user.email, 
                                                        "username": user.username})
        form2 = UpdateProfil(initial={"society": profile.society, 
                                                        "thingA": profile.thingA, 
                                                        "thingB": profile.thingB, 
                                                        "thingC": profile.thingC, 
                                                        "thingD": profile.thingD, 
                                                        "thingE": profile.thingE})

    return render(request, 'Register/edit_profile.html', locals())
```

and the template:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Email : </p>{{ form1.email }}
        <p>Nom d'utilisateur : </p>{{ form1.username }}
        <p>Société (entreprise, association, établissement...") :</p> 
        {{ form2.society }}
        <p>Si vous êtes membres d'un ou plusieurs centres pilotes, veuillez les cocher ci-dessous :</p> 
        <p>thingA : {{form2.thingA }}</p>
        <p>thingB : {{form2.thingB }}</p>
        <p>thingC : {{form2.thingC }}</p>
        <p>thingD : {{form2.thingD }}</p> 
        <p>thingE : {{form2.thingE }}</p>
        
        <button type="submit">Editer</button>
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deadline = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,
                                default=None,
                                verbose_name="Date limite de validité")
    thingA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thingB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thingC = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thingD = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thingE = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    society = models.CharField(max_length = 255, 
                                blank=True, null=True,
                                verbose_name="Société",
                                help_text="Le nom de votre entreprise, association, établissement...")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profil de {0}".format(self.user.username)
```

After trying different thing and reading everything I could on the topic without finding a solution working, I try to think outside the box : I thought that maybe it was because I didn't put the password inside the form, but it should'nt play a role here, right ?

So, maybe a permissions problem ? I try giving permisions, for both the model. Still not working...

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my English mistakes...

Comment: What happens when you add a user to the database, or change database values through the python shell

Comment: It works fine, I can add an user via the site or the panel admin, I can modify throught the panel admin, but not via the site

Comment: When you press save do you get any errors in the terminal?

Comment: Could you also please send your database models, as it might be an issue with that

Comment: No error in terminal, it's save as intended. I edited my post with de ProfilUser, for the User, it's the one from Django.auth

Comment: I looked through that and everything seems right to me, sorry I cannot help you.

Comment: thanks anyway, I hope to come to a solution =]

Comment: What happens when you change the and in your views (form1.valid and form2.valid) to or?

Comment: Ho, then I got an arror : "ValueError at /compte/edit/

The User could not be changed because the data didn't validate."

Answer (score 0):

So, I tinkered with my code a bit, and it's now working, I don't know why, and if someone know, I'm all ears!
I'll put it here, in case it could be helpful for others.

so, new view's code :

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
    profile = Profil.objects.get(user = user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UpdateUser(request.POST, instance=user)
        form2 = UpdateProfil(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
            return redirect("viewProfile") # Here is the only change I finished with

    else:
        form1 = UpdateUser(initial={"email": user.email, 
                                                        "username": user.username})
        form2 = UpdateProfil(initial={"society": profile.society, 
                                                        "thingA": profile.thingA, 
                                                        "thingB": profile.thingB, 
                                                        "thingC": profile.thingC, 
                                                        "thingD": profile.thingD, 
                                                        "thingE": profile.thingE})

    return render(request, 'Register/edit_profile.html', locals())
```

So, I guess the problem was with the httpResponseRedirect, don't know why, since there was no error, and nothing was saved, but well... I won't look a gift horse in the mouth! It's working now. 2020 suddenly seems a lot better! Until tomorrow that is =P

Thanks to those who tried to help me!